# Plot line segments from a datafile with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a datafile of following format (4 columns):

Size Xmid Ymid Angle

I want to plot line segments whose size is given in column 1, coordinates of the midpoint are given in columns 2 and 3, and angle with the x-axis is given in the last column.

How can I do that with gnuplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `vectors` plot style. It requires the data to be supplied as `x y xdelta ydelta`, where `x,y` denote the coordinates of the line-segment origin, and `xdelta/ydelta` stand for the corresponding displacements to the end point. However, this can be easily calculated from your input:

```
#this specifies that Gnuplot will expect angles in degrees
set angles degrees

plot 'input.dat' \
  u ($2 - $1*cos($4)/2):($3 - $1*sin($4)/2):($1*cos($4)):($1*sin($4)) \
  w vectors nohead \
  lc rgb 'black' lw 2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's really helpful.